# Flask socketio debug with eventlet and Redis spawns extra greenthreads?

Tags: flask, redis, werkzeug, eventlet, flask-socketio

I'm trying to put together a simple Flask / socketio / eventlet server that subscribes to Redis events. The behavior I'm seeing is that with Flask debug enabled, every time Werkzeug detects changes and restarts socketio, another one of my redis listeners is started as well (except the old listener doesn't exit).

Here's a working version with all of the socketio handlers removed:

```
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from flask.ext.redis import FlaskRedis
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()

with open('config/flask.json') as f:
    config_flask = json.load(f)

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='public', static_url_path='')
app.config.update(
      DEBUG= True,
      PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS= True,
      REDIS_URL= "redis://localhost:6379/0"
    )

redis_cache = FlaskRedis(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    cache = {}
    return render_template('index.html', **cache)

def redisReader():
    print 'Starting Redis subscriber'
    pubsub = redis_cache.pubsub()
    pubsub.subscribe('msg')
    for msg in pubsub.listen():
        print '>>>>>', msg

def runSocket():
    print "Starting webserver"
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = eventlet.GreenPool()
    pool.spawn(redisReader)
    pool.spawn(runSocket)
    pool.waitall()
```

Throw in some manual redis-cli publishing (PUBLISH msg himom)
This produces the following output:

```
Starting Redis subscriber
Starting webserver
 * Restarting with stat
>>>>> {'pattern': None, 'type': 'subscribe', 'channel': 'msg', 'data': 1L}
Starting Redis subscriber
Starting webserver
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 789-323-740
(22252) wsgi starting up on http://0.0.0.0:5000
>>>>> {'pattern': None, 'type': 'subscribe', 'channel': 'msg', 'data': 1L}
>>>>> {'pattern': None, 'type': 'message', 'channel': 'msg', 'data': 'himom'}
>>>>> {'pattern': None, 'type': 'message', 'channel': 'msg', 'data': 'himom'}
```

Why is the Redis listener getting started multiple times? If I make changes and save them, Werkzeug will start another one every time. How do I deal with this correctly?

Here's a list of the packages involved and their versions:

- Python 2.7.6
- Flask 0.10.1
- Werkzeug 0.11.4
- eventlet 0.18.4
- greenlet 0.4.9
- Flask-Redis 0.1.0
- Flask-SocketIO 2.2

** UPDATE **
I now have a partial solution. Everything above stays the same, except the pool behavior has been moved into Flask's 'before_first_request' function:

```
def setupRedis():
    print "setting up redis"
    pool = eventlet.GreenPool()
    pool.spawn(redisReader)

def runSocket():
    print "Starting Webserver"
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.before_first_request(setupRedis)
    print app.before_first_request_funcs
    runSocket()
```

The remaining issue is that 'before_first_request' does not handle the case where there are existing websockets, but that is a separate question.

Comment: If you look at your process list, are getting an increasing list of Python processes as the reloader keeps restarting your server? I'm thinking this could be caused by a bug in eventlet that does not allow a parent process to kill the child.

Comment: Please, provide versions for OS, Python, eventlet, werkzeug, flask, socketio.

Comment: I've added versions, @temoto. I believe they're all the latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here was to put my threading into a function called by Flask:

```
def setupRedis():
    pool = eventlet.GreenPool()
    pool.spawn(redisReader)
...
app.before_first_request(setupRedis)
```

This solved the extra threads left behind on Werkzeug restarts.

Answer (score 1):

Add simple `print(os.getpid())` and observe `ps aux`. You should notice there are two Python processes. Change `DEBUG=False,` and the "problem" is not reproducing, also there is one Python process now.

So the problem is that your code creates `redisReader` no matter if it's a "worker manager" or an actual "request handler" process. So, don't create and start that `pool` unconditionally. Consult Werkzeug documentation where is your "application init" event, and only start `redisReader` there.

Comment: This is getting closer to a solution, but I'm not 100%. I was able to add my redis reader to the 'before_first_request' function and that works. On werkzeug's reload only one redis thread is started/respawned. The problem now is the front-end needs a refresh to trigger that 'first request' to re-enable the thread. The existing websocket stays up but won't work again until a request is made...

Comment: I should also mention I can fire the 'first request' from another web browser tab and have things start working again for the original tab.

Comment: I don't understand the new problem. If the original issue is solved, please close it and create new question with details and steps to reproduce. If the original issue still persists, please update question with details.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. The new issue is different, so I'll update the question and then submit a separate question.